# Decrement days daily in membership site

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a database for membership site   where users has a **column day** .This is number of days left until users membership expire.

Right now I run cron job daily at 12 AM to decrement day column by 1.

Is this the better solution or any other ideas available ? using date of registration and current today date.

Comment: Why not have a column expiry date?

Comment: Just add a column where you save Last using Day and just compare that Date to Today and create your validation. Simple.

Answer (score 2):

Much better approach is to store membership expiration date and just compare with the current date.

Comment: This is one cool idea ...Actually user can buy number of days as addon...how can i extend the expiry days ? can u show me some sample

Comment: Update the column expiration date @Vishnu

Comment: You can use `DateTime` PHP class to handle dates. Check the documentation and note the very handy method `modify()`, which you can use like `$date->modify('+30 days');`

Comment: I mean  how get timestamp from n days from today , I dont find any answer or in google